# Using Javascript Array Filter method to apply logic

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been doing some JavaScript lately but am still pretty new to it.  I had a scenario where I needed to loop through an array and apply certain logic and was wondering about doing the standard loop and applying the logic or would it be better to make use of the array filter function.  I have an example below and I am aware I am not returning anything from the filter function etc (as I don't need it) but it still loops through the array, is minimal code and readable (in my opinion).  Would this be considered bad practice or do you think any issues could come from using the filter function like this?

```js
var numberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var value3;
var value5;

function Log() {
  console.log("------");
  console.log(numberArray);
  console.log(value3);
  console.log(value5);
  console.log("~~~~~~");
}

Log();

numberArray.filter(function(number){
  //Do whatever logic is required here i.e.

  if(number == 3){
    value3 = number
  }

  if(number == 5){
    value5 = number
  }
  
});

Log();
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what `filter` is meant to be used for. This is a use case for [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), instead.

Comment: You are not filtering, you are just check if 3 and 5 exists. Just use `indexOf` or `includes`.

Comment: @Liam I think this question is more about "Is `filter` the correct function to cycle inside an array and do stuff depending on what's inside?"  then "how do I do that?"